# OBIEE BI Server Seed Cache from ODI

Tags: oracle, obiee, oracle-data-integrator

I'm usind **ODI 12C** and **OBIEE 12C**.

By using [this post](https://www.rittmanmead.com/blog/2015/09/managing-the-obiee-bi-server-cache-from-odi-12c/) I have configured ODI and used "**SASeedQuery**" function by sending an **logical query** as a parameter but it returens this error : **[nQSError: 27047] Nonexistent table:"MyLogicalTable"** 
but when I send **physical query** as a parameter it runs with no error (but didn't cache anyting)
What should I do to make **SASeedQuery** undrestand **logical query** ? it there any configuration in ODI topology that I should did ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it, there was a property in ODI dataserver topology, named "NQ_SESSION.SELECTPHYSICAL" and set to "yes" , I removed it and it worked !!